# Duplicate definition for symbol __module_registered error

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc, ld

I get an error message from GHCi about a "duplicate definition for symbol __module_registered", like this:

```
 GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
           __module_registered
        whilst processing object file
           /usr/local/lib/ghc-6.2/HSfgl.o
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats is easy, probably indicates that when building a library for GHCi (HSfgl.o in the above example), you should use the -x option to ld.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Could you elaborate your answer please? Where do you write `-x` exactly?