# Duplicate definition for symbol

Tags: haskell, ld, ghc, ghci

I'm trying to compile a package (git-annex) under OpenBSD and I'm hitting some weird issues.

I keep getting

```
Loading package gnuidn-0.2.1 ... 
GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
    c_isascii
whilst processing object file
    /usr/local/lib/libidn.a
This could be caused by:
    * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
    * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
    * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

This was brought up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272056/resolving-ghc-i-found-a-duplicate-definition-for-symbol), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258259/bytestring-linking-in-ghc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392925/duplicate-definition-for-symbol-module-registered-error) but it didn't help me at all. I have checked to see if I have different versions of different packages (which I don't, according to ~/.cabal/lib and 'ghc-pkg list') and I have even tried recompiling libidn without the c_isascii symbol, which only resulted in the same error but about a different symbol (stringprep_utf8_to_unichar).

So right now I have no idea what to do. Any ideas?

EDIT: Added 'ghc-pkg list' to the sources I've checked for conflicting packages.

Comment: Don't look at `~/.cabal/lib` but at the output of `ghc-pkg list`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've never played with haskell stuff before. I checked it too but I didn't find anything strange.